# css working in one file but not the other

Tags: html, css

I have two html files using one css file. The one is working the other is not. 
In the first 'working' case, the html syntax is (css file is in the same directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Our first page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ourstyle.css"></head>
```

In the second 'not working' case, the html syntax is (css file is in one folder up):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Our second page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ourstyle.css"></head>
```

When running both files locally, the css file works, but on a server it does not.
I am using javascript and jquery in the second html file. I did what they suggested in the question on [Two Linked CSS Files Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962501/two-linked-css-files-not-working) but still did not work.
Please help.

PS This is my first question I am asking, so please let me know if I was not specific or clear enough. Thank you.

To clarify:
I don't have ourstyle.css in two separate directories in my local environment nor on a server. I have it only in the parent directory. So practically, I have the parent folder WWW, in which I have the 3 things:
1. the 'working' html script (with syntax 'href="ourstyle.css"')
2. the file ourstyle.css
3. the folder called cgi-bin, in which I have the 'not working' html script (with syntax 'href="../ourstyle.css"') 
The same folder structure I have locally and it is running. On server it does not.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried take out the `../` in second, since it is in same directory? `../` will search css in parent directory.

Comment: It is recommended to put all you css files into public/stylesheets folder.
so you can directly use them stylesheets/ourstyle.css

Comment: post the screen shot of your folder structure that shud help us find your mistake

Comment: Any 404 errors in your console?

Comment: Use your browser to view the source of your site (Right click -> View page source in Chrome) and click the CSS link. Tell us whether you see a tab which shows the content of the CSS file.

Comment: Why do you have the file ourstyle.css in two separate directories, in your local environment?

Comment: @dave I think he means that the second webpage is in a directory under the first page. The css file is in the same place both times

Comment: If this page is served from the root of the web server address (i.e. `http://domain/` as opposed to `http://domain/someFolder/`) you can't access files from the parent folder (think about it, what would the address be?) If that's not the case I can't tell you what's going on without seeing the site first hand. Can you give us the URL of the live site not working?

Comment: Your first url is linking to http://student.cryst.bbk.ac.uk/~bm002/stylesheets/ourstyle.css (works) but the latter `/stylesheets/ourstyle.css` resolves to: http://student.cryst.bbk.ac.uk/stylesheets/ourstyle.css (doesn't exist)

Comment: I got it. Thank you all for your invaluable input. To fix it I just used the absolute path rather than ../stylesheets/ourstyle.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather put ourstyles.css into a folder (like CSS) and then refer to them the same, i.e. /CSS/ourstyle.css (and not ../ourstyle and outstyle).  Putting your scripts in js folders and styles in css folders is good practice.  You will thank yourself later when you are working with lots of files.